# How to calculate Chi-Square density value only known P-value?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, chi-squared

Everywhere online there is how to calculate the Chi-Square density value given a confidence level: α/p value; but I can not find how one calculates the inverse? How to calculate the density value knowing only the α/p-value?

For example, if df = 4, and α=0.95, then how does one calculate the $\chi^2_4$?

In R this would be `qchisq(0.95, 4)`= 9.4877. What is the math behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\chi_4^2$ PDF is $\frac14xe^{-x/2}$ for $x\ge0$, so the CDF is $F(x)=\int_0^x\frac14te^{-t/2}dt=1-\frac12(x+2)e^{-x/2}$. Solving $\alpha=F(x)$ for $x$ requires the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), viz.$$-\tfrac1e(1-\alpha)=(-x/2-1)e^{-x/2-1}\implies x=-2(1+W(-\tfrac1e(1-\alpha))).$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got that CDF? Lets say for example that df = 6 instead of 4, then would it become $\int_0^x\frac{1}{48}t^2e^{-t/2}dt$

Comment: @notMyName The PDf [is well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution#Derivation_of_the_pdf_for_k_degrees_of_freedom), but turns out to be easiest to integrate when the number of degrees of freedom is even. However, I make the coefficient to be $\frac{1}{16}$, not $\frac{1}{48}$. (Bear in mind $\Gamma(s)=(s-1)!$.)